# Thin airfoil & lifting line theory principal value integrals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Reference: Batchelor, *Introduction to Fluid Dynamics* after eqn (6.9.8)

```
Assuming[{Element[n, Integers], n > 0, Element[a, Reals], a > 0, 
Element[t, Reals], t > 0}, 
Integrate[Cos[n*t]/(Cos[t] - Cos[a]), {t, 0, Pi}, PrincipalValue -> True]]
```

A "standard" definite integral `Pi* Sin[n a]/Sin[a]`. However, I can't get Mathematica to show equality between its result and this. And it is not an obvious listing In Gradshetyn either. Batchelor did  prove his result in a footnote from recursion after an indefinte integration for `n = 0`

> ```
> Log[Abs[Sin[(a + t)/2]/Sin[(a - t)/2]]]/Sin[a]
> ```

which Mathematica does do.  Please include successful code for the definite integrals. I was going to  try Mathematica extending the theory to oscillating lift but a prerequisite is that it can do the steady case easily and not recursively.

Comment: I don't see any clear statement of what you are asking us to do to help you. Could you please edit the question to provide that?

Comment: For `n=0` Mathematica finds $I_0=i\pi \csc {a}$  so the real part is 0. For `n=1`, Mathematica finds $I_1=\pi - i\pi \cot {a}$,  so the real part is $\pi $, as well as in Batchelor 's book. Then use the recurrent formula.

Comment: Please post your successful code as I am still have trouble with the definite integrals in Mathematica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) $n=0$

```
Integrate[1/(Cos[t] - Cos[a]), {t, 0, Pi}, PrincipalValue -> True]
(*ConditionalExpression[
 I \[Pi] Csc[
   a], (Re[ArcCos[Cos[a]]] < 0 || Re[ArcCos[Cos[a]]] > \[Pi] || 
    ArcCos[Cos[a]] \[NotElement] Reals) && Sin[a/2] >= 0 && 
  Cos[a/2] <= 0]*)
```

2)$n=1$

```
Integrate[Cos[t]/(Cos[t] - Cos[a]), {t, 0, Pi}, 
 PrincipalValue -> True]
(*ConditionalExpression[\[Pi] - I \[Pi] Cot[a], 
 Cos[a/2] >= 
   0 && (Re[ArcCos[Cos[a]]] < 0 || Re[ArcCos[Cos[a]]] > \[Pi] || 
    ArcCos[Cos[a]] \[NotElement] Reals) && Sin[a/2] <= 0]*)
```

We are interested in the real part of the resulting expressions:
$n=0, I_0=0$ and $n=1, I_1=\pi $ 
Thus, the real part of the resulting expressions is the same as in the book.  Then use the recurrent formula $I_{n+1}+I_{n-1}=2I_n\cos{a}$

Comment: It took awhile to see how to read these code answers and ignore the inserted backslashes and Mathematica's conditions. They are simpler than what v 7 gave me and allow me to see its Re part was also zero. Ignore. Ia >= \[Pi] it had
I0 =Csc[a] (I*Pi + Log[2] - Log[-2 Cos[a/2]] + Log[Cos[a/2]])